# Mongoid nested has_one problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am trying to update a nested has_one model using mongoid but it will not persist the has_one association

im running Rails 3.07 & Mongoid 2.2

widget model

```
class Widget
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :permissions, :default => []

end
```

permission model

```
class Permission   
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :admin, :type => Boolean, :default => false  

  has_one :user

  embedded_in :widget 

end
```

user model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :permission

end
```

Heres the results im getting from rails console;

```
@widget.permissions << Permission.new(:user => current_user)
 => [#<Permission _id: 4e5aced1c155df4b33000001, _type: nil, admin: false>]

@widget.save
 => true

@widget.permissions.first.user
 => #<User _id: 4e5ac71ec155df470f000001, _type: nil, email: "ada ..... >
```

Appears as if the user is saved, however it is not persisted to mongo.
The permission is being saved but has no user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you be using "embedded_in" rather than "belongs_to" in the User model?

Comment: its not embedded its linked so referenced_in would be better. references_one & referenced_in would probably be better but i understood they are aliases anyway

Comment: Ah ok - and does mongoid cascade saves to linked documents? I don't remember reading anywhere that it does - but that doesn't mean it doesn't. You only save the widget - if it doesn't cascade you won't save the person.

Comment: Im hoping it does, im probably just doing some thing stupid. Certainly  acts like its saving the docs in the console... thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: No worries. Don't have environment to test it myself at the moment, but what happens if you reload the widget in the console by doing Widget.find() ? Is the person still there? What makes you think it looks like they're saving? Bear in mind that in most cases the _id is generated on the client side by the mongo driver, so the document doesn't necessarily have to have been saved to have one.

Comment: it was my retarded-ness, has_one :user in the Permission model should have been belongs_to :user, the User model does not neet a backwards association, and as it was the user was getting a permission_id in the  user model. It was persisting the data but storing the relationship incorrectly. cheers